# How do I access my Raspberry Pi via SSH without the need for a password every single time?

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, ssh-keys, raspbian

I'm a beginner to Raspberry Pi and SSH based connections, and I want to access my Raspberry Pi running on Raspbian, from my Windows 10 computer, via remote SSH on Visual Studio code. I have watched several tutorials, like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z46YbczqbiE) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKXMyln_5q4&t=200s), on how to create SSH key pairs, and I have followed the instructions perfectly, but the process still requires me to enter the user's password.

I can say for sure that I have copied the public key into the Pi in the correct directory (~/.ssh/authoirized_keys), and and that the config file on my pc also points to the right address of the private key and it looks like this

```
Host Raspberry
    HostName 192.168.0.69
    User pi
    IdentityFile C:/Users/ashka/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    IdentitiesOnly true
```

Is there something in between that causes the handshake to fail, or is there some aspect of this that I am overlooking?

I would really appreciate some help with this, and I would not mind having to do the whole process all over again, if it means I can finally get this over with.

Comment: Which directory _specifically_? Which config file, and which setting in that config file? We do need to know the current actual state of the system, as there's no way to know which steps of which tutorial were followed or not followed.

Comment: I have edited the original question to answer some of your questions, but can you please explain what you mean by the state of the system? Also, I have followed the instructions of the first video up until the generation of the key pairs. After that, I ssh'd into the Pi and edited the authorized_keys with the help of nano and copy pasted the contents of the public key directly into it, instead of using the method mentioned in the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to do this. For anyone trying this, I recommend you go through the [first](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z46YbczqbiE) video thoroughly and not miss any steps.

Comment: The video may go down, and things can get moved. Having a self contained answer is a better idea for the future.